# nginx with php-fpm or standard LAMP in heavy load sites

Tags: php, nginx, load, lamp, opcache

I'm currently using Nginx with php-fpm 5.4 (Centos 6.4)

I want to switch to standard LAMP installation with OpCache for performance improvement.

I decided to go with Nginx initially because it's very lightweight and can handle load, but now that all my static resources comes from CDN (amazon / cloudflare) i wander if Nginx is really better then the standard LAMP.

what's the recommended configuration (php wise, go with 5.5 or stay with php-fpm 5.4+nginx) for heavy load sites?

thx,

Comment: why go through the hassle to change it if its not causing any issues? its not like Apache will be much better.

Comment: cause i strive for better....? :)

Comment: thats good :). i personally wouldn't switch to php 5.5 so quickly. cause some time new versions can have issues and you may have to wait till the next version or patch. stick with 5.4 for now. and for 5.4 you can get OpCache with PECL

Comment: @Jayasankar 5.5 was released 6 months ago. And is currently at 5.5.5. How long do you want to wait?

Comment: @DannyValariola It is impossible to answer your question. Heavy load is not a real unit. And even if it was it would still be impossible to tell you anything useful because we need to have all the information about what you are running, what your setup looks like hard numbers about connections, size of requests/responses, current load, current bottleneck. If you want better benchmark it and try other things out and benchmark again.

Comment: @PeeHaa - i am aware of all the "missing" variables in the equation, but my question was if i have a CDN serving static content what is the better approach for installation on centos servers (assuming i have a standard webpage / php app)

Comment: You should totally go for php-fpm and nginx. Not that this is a useful answer for you, but just because this question is subjective so you get a subjective answer.